# What's the meaning of "in the 90s"

Tags: phrases, numbers

From NPR (describing how the honeybees keep warm):

> They (honeybees) actually kind of cluster together and form a bee ball around the queen and then vibrate their wings and that keeps the whole nest up and warm ***in the 90s***.
> <sup>([Source](http://wrur.org/post/upside-bitter-cold-it-kills-bugs-kill-trees))</sup>

Generally, "in the 90s" means a time, just as "the 1990s", but it seems that here the phrase doesn't represent a time, it's more like a temperature or something else. Can anyone give a reasonable interpretation of it? Thanks!

Comment: It's temperature, not time. It means between 90°F and 99°F (or, ***in the 30s***, using the Celsius scale). [Related](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15455).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar to the way “in the 90s” would indicate something occurred in one or more of the years 1990-1999, “up [. . .] in the 90s” in this case means that bees behaving in that way can elevate the temperatures of their nests to somewhere in the 90- to 99-degree range. We can safely assume that he is referring to the Fahrenheit scale because he is in the USA.

This construction can be used in a great many ways. In fact, you can even say silly things like:

> She had an approval rating in the 90s in the 90s.

This would mean the official in question had an approval rating in the 90- to 99-percent range during some span of time in the 1990-1999 range of years.

Comment: You can also assume that the temperature is in the Fahrenheit scale because 90° Celsius would likely cause the bees to burst into flame...

Comment: @Doc I nearly included that.

Comment: I almost left a comment about how 90° isn't hot enough for actual bee flamage (water only boils at 100°).  But then I decided not to.  ;-)